# How does this loop works?

Tags: shell

I have this code and I need to find an explanation to it especially the part 
set files ="$files test$k.ppm"

what does it do?

```
set files = ""
set k = 100
while($k <210)
set files = "$files test$k.ppm"
@ k = $k +10
end
```

Comment: Does this code run in any environment?

Answer (score 0):

https://explainshell.com/

> set is for setting variables

This row set variable "files" into String with value as "{files} test{counter}.ppm"
`files ="$files test$k.ppm"`

> At the beginning files is empty String...

```
#1st iteration (IN: files = "", k = 100)
files = "" + test100.ppm
#out files = test100.ppm

#2nd iteration (files = "" + test100.ppm; k = 110)
files = test100.ppm test110.ppm
#out files = test100.ppm test110.ppm

#Last iteration will be something like 
test100ppm test110ppm {...} test200.ppm
```

Nothing else